# android restoring webview during orientation change in tabhost tabs

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost, restore

In my application i have a tabhost with three tabs. All the three tabs has a webview and i load different URLS.

I want to add support for orientation change so that the web pages will not be reloaded each time the configuration is changed. So i added the following additional code to all three tab activities

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.review_web);
    webDetailInfo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webReview);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        webDetailInfo.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    else{.....


@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i("onsave", "detailweb");
        webDetailInfo.saveState(outState);
    }
```

Now when i change the orientation of the phone what i see is , the webpage is not reloaded which is right. But all the three tabs shows the same data which is the content of webview in first tab.

Please help me to understand this behavior and the right way of implementing it.

Source code for one of the tab activity is given below. I have three activities like this.
What i see is that when the orientation changes while in any of these tabs, all the thre tab activities and the parent activity that set these tabs get killed.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.idg.project.R;
import com.idg.project.entity.ScannedProduct;
import com.idg.project.services.ScannedProductDataAccessManager;
import com.idg.project.utils.ReviewWebClient;

public class ReviewWebActivity extends BaseActivity {

    WebView webReview;
    String reviewUrl;
    ProgressDialog progreesDialogue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final BaseActivity MyActivity = ReviewWebActivity.this;

        setContentView(R.layout.review_web);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webReview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);


        else{
        ScannedProduct product = getReviewUrl();
        reviewUrl = product.getReviewLink();

        if (reviewUrl.equals("")) {
            String err = product.getErrorCode();
            if (err.equals(""))
                err = "No Data Available for this product";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No Data Available for this product", 1).show();
            if (progreesDialogue != null && progreesDialogue.isShowing() ) {
                progreesDialogue.dismiss();
            }
            return;
        } else {

            webReview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webReview);
            webReview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            webReview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            if (isOnline()) {
                webReview.loadUrl(reviewUrl);
            } else {
                showAlertMessge("Network Connection Error "
                        + "\nCheck your network connection");
            }
        }}
    }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i("onsave", "reviewweb");
        ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webReview)).saveState(outState);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("ondestroy", "progressdialog null");
        progreesDialogue = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add this code in your activity tag in manifest file like this

```
<activity android:name=".Slime"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

without this on every orientation change on create method is called so your webView is reloading but if you add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

this line in your activity so that in that activity when orientation is changed at that time control will not go on onCreate() instead of that control will go on this method

```
// Called on rotation. 
// Does not call onDestroy anymore due to android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in manifest
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

and you can change property of controls..

I hope this will hwlp you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my issue is even if i handle the configuration change as you said, the savedinstance is not getting the right content for each tab but its the same data.

Comment: @preetha I think webView.saveState(Bundle) this method Save the state of this WebView used in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView. and also I think that when you change your orientation of your phone it saves only that particular tab's webView but I am not sure about that .....I think  you should try once android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" because in that you don't need to store saveState..

Comment: Thank you . I cannot set this flag because i have different layouts for portrait view and landscape view. If we set this flag, the layouts will not change when orientation changes. If this was not required this solution will workout.